# jQuery UI tabs - getting URL of tab loaded with Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have jQuery UI tabs using AJAX. My problem is I can't seem to retrieve the url which was loaded inside a tab.

For example - I get URL of loaded tab like this

```
var links = $("#tabs > ul").find("li a");
var selectedTab = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'selected');
var url = $.data(links[selectedTab], 'load.tabs');
```

Where url is the url of currently opened tab.

In the tab I have an AJAX call, which calls the same url but with some parameters, i.e.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url = url+'?parameter=value'
});
```

Once this call is executed, a newly created URL is called, tab is reloaded, but the variable which retrieves the loaded tab url remains the same, which means my parameters are missing.

Ideas?

Comment: Here, we can find with small snippet of code too http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Comment: What is it exactly you're referring to?

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, I am loading tabs in AJAX, but I can only obtain initial tab URL, not a new URL if it changes.

Comment: "In the tab I have an AJAX call...", where in the tab did you make this call? And could you provide all the options in the `$.ajax()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#tabs").tabs({  
    load:  function(event, ui){  
        var anchor = ui.tab.find(".ui-tabs-anchor");  
        var url = anchor.attr('href');  
    }  
});
```

This will save the current tab URL in variable **url**

Answer (score 0):

you can keep a global variable for the URL.

Comment: I'd have to do that the page that contains tab div definition and that's not really what I want to do...